# Query for a cache hit rate graph with prometheus

Tags: spring-boot, grafana, prometheus, caffeine

I'm using Caffeine cache with Spring Boot application. All metrics are enabled, so I have them on Prometheus and Grafana.

Based on `cache_gets_total` metric I want to build a **HitRate** graph.

I've tried to get *a cache hits*:

```
delta(cache_gets_total{result="hit",name="myCache"}[1m])
```

and *all gets* from cache:

```
sum(delta(cache_gets_total{name="myCache"}[1m]))
```

Both of the metrics works correctly and have values. But when I'm trying to get a hit ratio, I have no data points. Query I've tried:

```
delta(cache_gets_total{result="hit",name="myCache"}[1m]) / sum(delta(cache_gets_total{name="myCache"}[1m]))
```

Why this query doesn't work and how to get a HitRate graph based on information, I have from Spring Boot and Caffeine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run both ("cache hits" and "all gets") queries individually in prometheus and compare label sets you get with results.
For "/" operation to work both sides have to have *exactly* the same labels (and values). Usually some aggregation is required to "drop" unwanted dimensions/labels (like: if you already have one value from both queries then just wrap them both in sum() - before dividing).

Comment: Got it, tried `sum(delta(cache_gets_total{result="hit",name="myCache"}[1m]))/sum(delta(cache_gets_total{name="myCache"}[1m]))` and it works, thank you!

Comment: You should use rate rather than delta with counters.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is recommended to use [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) instead of [delta](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#delta) for calculating the increase of the [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter) over the specified lookbehind window. The `increase()` function properly handles counter resets to zero, which may happen on service restart, while `delta()` would return incorrect results if the given lookbehind window covers counter resets.

Next, Prometheus searches for pairs of time series with identical sets of labels when performing `/` operation. Then it applies individually the given operation per each pair of time series. Time series returned from  `increase(cache_gets_total{result="hit",name="myCache"}[1m])` have at least two labels: `result="hit"` and `name="myCache"`, while time series returned from `sum(increase(cache_gets_total{name="myCache"}[1m]))` have zero labels because [sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) removes all the labels after the aggregation.

Prometheus provides the solution to this issue - `on()` and `group_left()` modifiers. The `on()` modifier allows limiting the set of labels, which should be used when searching for time series pairs with identical labelsets, while the `group_left()` modifier allows matching multiple time series on the left side of `/` with a single time series on the right side of `/` operator. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching). So the following query should return cache hit rate:

```
increase(cache_gets_total{result="hit",name="myCache"}[1m])
  / on() group_left()
sum(increase(cache_gets_total{name="myCache"}[1m]))
```

There are alternative solutions exist:

1. To remove all the labels from `increase(cache_gets_total{result="hit",name="myCache"}[1m])` with `sum()` function:

```
sum(increase(cache_gets_total{result="hit",name="myCache"}[1m]))
  /
sum(increase(cache_gets_total{name="myCache"}[1m]))
```

2. To wrap the right part of the query into [scalar()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#scalar) function. This enables `vector op scalar` matching rules described [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators):

```
increase(cache_gets_total{result="hit",name="myCache"}[1m])
  /
scalar(sum(increase(cache_gets_total{name="myCache"}[1m])))
```

It is also possible to get cache hit rate for all the caches with a single query via `sum(...) by (name)` template:

```
sum(increase(cache_gets_total{result="hit"}[1m])) by (name)
  /
sum(increase(cache_gets_total[1m])) by (name)
```